# Memory leak on popToViewController

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

Hi 
I am using following method to go back to one of the previous view. This is working. But I got two issues with this.

1. This line gives a memory leak when I use Instrument.
2. After popup to particular view, when I press left navigation button (back button) just only this button will disappear and view will remain.

Can anyone please let me know how to overcome these issues?

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you solve the leak issue?

Comment: I am not sure this an issue anymore as we use ARC.

Answer (score 1):

try `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` if you just with to remove current view from the view hierarchy,

Comment: freely typed - unsure of syntax errors but definately on them lines

Comment: the OP asks about popping (sound funny :) ) view controllers. Not pushing.

Comment: ahh sorry mis-read, just [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; if you wish to remove from view,

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
In my view hierarchy there are 4 view. I need to go back from view 4 to 2 directly

Comment: my first attempt at answering would have done just that, should you just changed the method to popToViewController rather than my suggested pushViewController.

Comment: In your first attempt you suggested to create a new viewcontroller and push it, while the task is to pop viewcontrollers until a certain existing one is reached. How can you say "it would have done just that"?

Comment: it would have simply popped to the viewController- i see what your trying to accomplish, therefore, make a reference to your VC from self.navigationItem.viewControllers, pop to that, this does what you require

Comment: When I change to pop following erros are given.
*** Assertion failure in -[UINavigationController popToViewController:transition:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1448.89/UINavigationController.m:2043
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'

Cheers

Comment: Guys can you please let me know how can I put more code there? Because its only limit around 600 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you, as you describe, just wants to pop just the active viewController, you can use

```
 - (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW3).

If this still give problems, there is something wrong with your viewController hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 
This will only go back to previous view from current. In my view hierarchy there are 4 view. I need to go back from view 4 to 2 directly.

Comment: ok. misread. so in this case you use the right method. but your are not passing in the right viewcontroller. otherwise it would work.

Comment: I am afraid, that method is working. But I got a memory leak and the popup view's navigation bar button is not working. 
How can I overcome that. 
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hi agree with the above answers 
try these methods carefully

- > [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
- > [self.navigationController popToViewController:(UIViewController*)
  >   animated:(BOOL)];

*Working with iOS5*.

- 

> [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)];